# How to decrease the extra padding of Textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have a Textfield which is having some default padding. I want to remove the top and bottom padding. How can I do it?

Below is the image

[image]

I tried giving maxLines property to Textfield but it didn't work.

[image]

```
                                   TextField(
                                         onChanged:
                                         bloc.changeRole,
                                         decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                             contentPadding:
                                             EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                 vertical: 0,
                                                 horizontal: 15.0),
                                             border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                                 borderSide:
                                                 const BorderSide(
                                                     width: 2.0,
                                                     style:
                                                     BorderStyle
                                                         .solid),
                                                 borderRadius:
                                                 BorderRadius
                                                     .circular(
                                                     50.0)),
                                             focusedBorder:
                                             OutlineInputBorder(
                                               borderSide:
                                               const BorderSide(
                                                   color:
                                                   Colors.grey,
                                                   width: 2.0),
                                               borderRadius:
                                               BorderRadius.circular(
                                                   50.0),
                                             ),
                                             hintText: 'Role',
                                             hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                                                 color: Colors.grey,
                                                 fontWeight:
                                                 FontWeight.bold),
                                             errorText: snapshot.error),
                                       )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `isDense:true`

```
TextField(
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
        isDense: true,
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 15.0),
      ),
),
```